# <kendo:pager pageSizes="pageSizes">

Tags: javascript, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to set pageSize in kendo:grid.

I've searched and I know it can be set via javascript using

```
pageable:{                 
pageSizes: [10, 20, 35, 50, 75, 100]
     },
```

but the kendo:grid which I have does not use JavaScript. It uses Kendo-tag libraries in jsp.

This is my code structure:

```
        <kendo:grid name="NameOfGrid" groupable="false" sortable="true">

            <kendo:grid-pageable pageSizes="true" refresh="false" > </kendo:grid-pageable>
              <kendo:grid-columns>
                 <kendo:grid-column title=" " field=" " width="60" sortable="true" />

             There are new more <kendo:grid-colum>

                            </kendo:grid-columns>
    <kendo:dataSource data="${"dataSource"}" pageSizes="[10,20,30,40]"> </kendo:dataSource>

        </kendo:grid>
```

So, i'm using this way to set kendo:grid and everything work's perfect, but here i want to set own pageSize, by default when pageSize is kept true it has dropdown [5,10,20 and All ] but i want to change it and keep as [10, 20, 35, 50, 75, 100]. 
 ..

so can anyone help or show an example on how to set using . There are few documentation using it but i couldnot find a proper example.http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/pager

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: From using the .Net equivalent code I think you have your pageSize declaration in the wrong place. You need to move the `defined` page sizes you have in the datasource object to the grid pageable `pageSizes=true` the datasource doesn't have a pageSizes object it has a pageSize property for defining the current page size of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an Object array as predefined values to the pageSizes option, e.g.:

```
<%
  Object pageSizes[] = {10, 50, 100, 250};
%>
...
<kendo:grid name="grid" groupable="true" sortable="true" style="height:550px;">
  <kendo:grid-pageable refresh="true" pageSizes='<%= pageSizes %>' ...>
```